# The map Ti=i+1 mod N is uniquely ergodic

Tags: ergodic-theory

I have a set $X=\{1,2,...,N\}$ and the map $T:X \to X$: $Ti=i+1 \text{ mod } N$. 
Now I want to show that $T$ is uniquely ergodic and find the unique measure.

I know it holds that $T^Nx=x$ iff $\frac{1}{N} \sum^{N-1}_{i=0} \delta_{T^ix} \in M(X,T)$. 
So I know for sure that $\upsilon=\frac{1}{N} \sum^{N-1}_{i=0} \delta_{T^ix}$ is a $T$ invariant probability measure.

So now I want to show that for all arbitrary $T$ invariant probability measure $m$ holds that $m=\upsilon$.

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't $X$ contain $0$ as $T(n-1) = 0$ ? (If $T$ is a map from $X$ to $X$.) I don't know, as $T$'s target is not even defined.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. But $X$ contains $N$ instead of $0$.. I think this is not very nice, but right.

Comment: We agree. ;-) Why wouldn't you for instance just say that $T$ is the circular permutation $(1 \dots N )$ ?

Comment: I tink I can say that $T$ is a circular permutation.

Comment: Actually, if what you say is true for a circular permutation of length $N$, it is true for any circular permutation of length $N$.

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is an invariant measure, then $m(x) = m(T^{-1}(x)) = m(x-1)$ for all $x$, where $x-1$ is understood modulo $N$, and $m(x) = m(\{x\})$. This implies that $m(x) = m(y)$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: I don't get you completely... Why can you say now that T is uniquely ergodic? And is the measure $m = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{i=0} \delta_{T^ix}$?

Comment: @user15888 Yes, the measure given by Lukas Geyer is the one you said. And since any invariant (so any ergodic) measure must have this form, we know that $T$ is uniquely ergodic.